# Ignite Node fails on Startup in Docker Container

Tags: docker, ignite

I'm starting my nodes within Docker containers that I have created using the "ignite.sh" script that is deployed within the image. Recently, I turned on native persistence for my default data region configuration, and now the node fails to start with this exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheUtils.affinityNode(GridCacheUtils.java:1374)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager$CachePredicate.dataNode(GridDiscoveryManager.java:3205)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager.cacheAffinityNode(GridDiscoveryManager.java:1894)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.ValidationOnNodeJoinUtils.validate(ValidationOnNodeJoinUtils.java:346)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor.createCacheContext(GridCacheProcessor.java:1201)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor.startCacheInRecoveryMode(GridCacheProcessor.java:2291)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor.access$1700(GridCacheProcessor.java:202)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor$CacheRecoveryLifecycle.afterBinaryMemoryRestore(GridCacheProcessor.java:5387)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager.restoreBinaryMemory(GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager.java:1075)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager.startMemoryRestore(GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager.java:2068)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.start(IgniteKernal.java:1254)
```

It seems like I should be able to start the node and have time to activate the cluster before it fails.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you use an Ignite version prior to the 2.8.1 (maybe 2.8.0). There was an issue related to the `DiscoverySPI` not yet started at the point of a node validation. It could lead to this behaviour in case of a region with persistence enabled. Here's the [link](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-12805) to the ticket. Just update it to a fresher version.